# Minimum Sample size between two samples for a specified confidence interval/level with sigma known

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, confidence-interval, interval-arithmetic

Hi math stack exchange,

I came across the following question and found it quite interesting and am struggling to solve it. I haven't seen anything like it because it is both two sample and has sigma known. If anyone could give me some insight as to how to begin looking at the problem would be appreciated

Let $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ and $Y_1, \ldots , Y_n$ be independent random samples from the $N(\mu_{X}, 2)$ and
$N(\mu_{Y} , 2)$ distributions, respectively. Calculate the minimal value of $n$ so that one can be
95% confident the interval
$[\bar{X} − \bar{Y}− 1, \bar{X} − \bar{Y}+ 1]$
contains the true value of $\mu_X − \mu_Y$.

My idea is to set up the usual confidence interval for one side for a sigma unknown as the following form:

$1= \sqrt{(\sigma^2/n) +(\sigma^2/n)}\cdot 1.96$

$1= \sigma\cdot \sqrt{1/n +1/n}\cdot 1.96$

$1=2\cdot(2/n)\cdot 1.96$  ($2$ here at the start subbed in for sigma

And then solve for $n$?

Does this approach work?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is a good approach. Note that you lost sqrt in the last equation.

Comment: You can *edit* your [existing posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068164/minimum-sample-size-for-two-means-confidence-interval-with-known-standard-deviat) to get them 'out of hold' by adding context as you have done here, instead of a new post.